# Google Ads showing at very low rate in Xamarin app

Tags: admob

We're using AdMob in our Xamarin app. On the simulator or with dev builds the test ads display very quickly and every time.

However, after we published the app to the App Store, the ads very rarely display. On my personal device with the App Store version of our app installed, I never see the ads. This is the same with many, many of our users. Our requests over the last 7 days are 4 to 1 request to impressions. Some days it's more like 10 to 1.

I've verified our bank account and everything seems to be done correctly.

Is it possible I missed a setting for our release over our dev builds?

There's no issues under Policy Center.

Answer (score 0):

It took about 2 weeks but now the ads seem to always get displayed now on all, or almost all devices. I didn't make any changes so I'm not sure why it took so long.